# API_Defining an array

Tags: api, karate

How can I define array below in Intellij? I am sending this API request and getting error:

```
sharedAccountDetails [
Account details.
SharedAccountItem{
accountNumber string
Account number of the user. 

accountName string
Account name of the user. 

accountType string

Account type saving/current etc.

branchCode string
Branch Code. 


}]
```

This is my request below:

```
And request { 'channel': 'email'}

And request { 'accountNumber': '000000000'}
And request { 'accountName': 'Mr Bytes C'}
And request { 'accountType': 'Current Account'}
And request { 'branchCode': '000'}
```

It is requesting for the arrays. how do I define them?
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Tshilidzi

Comment: the error I am getting is below:

 "ErrorFields": [
    {
      "Fields": "proofofAccountRequest.SharedAccountDetails",
      "Message": "Account details are required"
    }
  ]
}

11:41:37.435 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - status code was: 400, expected: 200, response time: 218,

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand but can you look at the demo examples of Karate carefully. Looks like you have to understand how to use JSON. See this example below:

```
And request
"""
{
  sharedAccountDetails: [
    { accountNumber: '000000000', 'accountName': 'Mr Bytes C', 'accountType': 'Current Account' }
  ]
}
"""
```